# Missing Boot Menu

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, multi-boot

I have windows 8 and windows 7 installed in my system, yet I don't have a boot menu. When I load my computer it goes straight to windows 8.

I installed EasyBCD and tried to recreate the boot files but still don't see the boot menu. If I use ireboot I still can get to my windows 7 partition but it means first I have to load windows 8, reboot and then load windows 7.

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) it has a built in utility to find all your Windows partitions and fix your Master Boot Record to include them, and then you should be able to dual boot.

Comment: Visual BCD Editor is real nice, but it difficult to understand compared to EasyBCD.  I have been working on my own USB Boot menu, and the menu is always missing (using EasyBCD), so I used Visual BCD Editor to take a look and can't find anything the matter.